# Proof Verification: Baby Rudin Exercise 4.4 Alternative Proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

> Rudin 4.4: Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous mappings of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$, and let $E$ be a dense subset of $X$. Prove that $f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$. If $g(p) = f(p)$ for all $p \in E$, prove that $g(p) = f(p)$ for all $p \in X$.

Now, I have finished a proof of the first part:

**Proof (Part a):** Let $y \in f(X)$ be arbitrary. Now, let $x \in X$ be such that $f(x) = y$. Since $E$ is dense in $X$, $x$ is either in $E$ or a limit point of $E$. If $x \in E$, then we see that $y = f(x) \in f(E)$. Now, suppose $x$ is a limit point of $E$, then there exists $\{x_n\}$ in $E$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$. Since $f$ is a continuous function it preserves limits we see that:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = f\big(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n\big) = f(x) = y,$$

and thus we see that $y$ is a limit point of $f(E)$. Therefore, it follows that $f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$.

However, I proved the second part of this exercise using a previous exercise, and am uncertain if it holds for mapping into general metric spaces $Y$.

**Proof (Part b):** Notice that for all $p \in E$ we see that

$$f(p) = g(p) \Leftrightarrow f(p) - g(p) = 0$$.

Since $f,g \in C^0(X)$ it follows that $f-g \in C^0(X)$. Therefore, we see that $p \in Z(f-g)$ where $f-g$ is continuous. The equivalence shows that $E = Z(f-g)$, and thus $Z(f-g)$ is dense in $X$. Moreover, since $Z(f-g)$ is closed, it follows that $Z(f-g) = X$ since $Z(f-g)$ is dense and closed in $X$. Therefore, it follows that $E = Z(f-g) = X$ and we have that

$$f(p) - g(p) = 0 \Leftrightarrow f(p) = g(p),$$

as desired.

**My hesitations with this proof:** I believe that I am valid in saying that $f-g$ is continuous on $X$ given that $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $X$. However, I am unsure that $Z(f-g)$ is closed given that $f-g:X \rightarrow Y$ maps into a general metric space. It makes sense if $Y = \mathbb{R}$ or $Y = \mathbb{C}$, but does this holds for any metric space?

Comment: $f - g$ doesn't make sense when $Y$ doesn't have addition. Instead, use $Z = \{p \in X : f(p) = g(p)\}$.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I implicitly assumed a vector space structure. I knew there was some assumption I made that was too strong. I’ll fix this proof when I get home!

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2400365/861687)   (both post and answer) slick proof for part(b).